# WFS data not loading in full

Tags: qgis, wfs

I am relatively new to QGIS and WFS,

I am loading a map via WFS with GML data from *The Danish Board of Data*, it is a large database of geometries (contour lines) covering Denmark. However, when I load them, they load differently and incompletely every time.

Is it an overload? Can I limit the extend of the data?
Do I make any sense?

[image]

Comment: Is it a public service? If so, it might be useful to include the link in your question

Comment: Semi-public, I can send a link in a private message, but not public.

Comment: make sure you don't have a MaxFeatures parameter in your request

Comment: WFS servers have often, or usually, a limit for maximum number of features that can be fetched with one request. It does not always appear in the GetCapabilities, but WFS 2.0 servers may show something like this `<ows:Constraint name="CountDefault">
<ows:NoValues/> <ows:DefaultValue>2000</ows:DefaultValue> </ows:Constraint>`

Comment: I have made a token: 

https://api.dataforsyningen.dk/DHMhoejdekurver_GML3_DAF?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&token=123456ae9de65ed01f144d0200f5203c

There's also a "Get capabilities" file, it XML, but I am unsure how to use it how to use it.

Comment: what is your goal? wfs should be used when Creating Updating or Deleting data. For reading I would suggest using WMS or Vector Tiles. Even if it is not mentioned in the Capabilities document, your WFS service may be limited on the max returned features per request